# multiprocessing in Python not using all cores

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I am trying to process several folders that contain many rasters; in each folder, there are rasters with different dates on the same area. In order to save some time, I want to use the multiprocessing (or multithreading?) module to work in parallel.

Basically, my script does this: for one pixel, it makes some calculation on the first pixel and loads it to a `numpy` array if the number is higher than the previous one that was in the `numpy` array; then it continues with another pixel. The result should be several `numpy` arrays (one per folder).
It works fine without multiprocessing; when I try to multiprocess it, it gets very slow and doesn't take advantage of all 10 cores:

[image]

Here is my code:

```py
import os, sys, math, time, datetime
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from osgeo import gdal,gdal_array,osr
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
import multiprocessing

#prints full size numpy array instead of extract

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

#define tresholds for dNBR, NBR and NDVI difference (ratio NDVIafter/NDVIbefore)

dNBRthreshold=0.15
RdNBRthreshold=0.4
NDVIdiffThreshold=0.1


def proc (path):
    #print information to a log file
    log = open(path+"\\myprog.log", "a")
    sys.stdout = log

    #create a list of all files in the current directory 
    ListImages=[]
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
                ListImages.append(os.path.join(path, file))
    #sort the list aphabetically
    ListImages.sort()
    print ("Image list: ", ListImages)

    #create empty numpy array the same size as the first image and with number of bands defined by user
    firstImage=gdal.Open(ListImages[0])
    band0 = firstImage.GetRasterBand(1)
    arrayOfFirstImage = band0.ReadAsArray()
    listEmpty=[]

    #create numpy array with same size as first image but dimension defined by user in "range"
    for x in range(30):
        name="emptyArray_" + str(x)
        #create raster with same size as first image
        name=np.full_like(arrayOfFirstImage, np.nan, dtype=np.double)
        listEmpty.append(name)
    arrayStack=np.stack(listEmpty)
    num_dim, num_rows,num_cols = arrayStack.shape
    listRows = list(range(num_rows))    

    #creates loop over all pixels in raster
    for row in range(num_rows):
        print("row number: ", row)
        for col in range(num_cols):
            #reset counter for band as script is working with a new pixel; cntrForBand is used to change arrayStack bands that will be written on
            cntrForBand=0
            print("col number: ", col)
            #loop for all images in list ListImages to get image 1
            #user ITER to be able to jump 7 o 22 loops
            iterListImages = iter(ListImages)
            for image in iterListImages:
                #get number of image in the List of Images
                indexImage1 = ListImages.index(image)
                #get its full path
                img1Path=os.path.abspath(image)
                print ("path image 1: " + img1Path)
                print ("index Image 1: ",indexImage1)
            
                #open geotiff with gdal
                img = gdal.Open(image)
                #get first band data of image 1: NDVI value
                band1Image1=img.GetRasterBand(1)
                #get second band data of image 1: NBR value
                band2Image1 = img.GetRasterBand(2)
                               
                ## compute statistics of band 1
                if band1Image1.GetMinimum() is None or band1Image1.GetMaximum()is None:
                    band1Image1.ComputeStatistics(0)
                    print("Statistics computed.")
                    
                ## compute statistics of band 2
                if band2Image1.GetMinimum() is None or band2Image1.GetMaximum()is None:
                    band2Image1.ComputeStatistics(0)
                    print("Statistics computed.")
                    
                #converts gdal array (raster or band) into a numpy array:
                band1Image1asArray = band1Image1.ReadAsArray()
                #print ("NDVI array= ",band1Image1asArray)    
                band2Image1asArray = band2Image1.ReadAsArray()
                #Get NDVI value of pixel of interest
                itemNDVIimage1=band1Image1asArray[row][col]
                print("itemNDVIimage1: ",itemNDVIimage1)
                #Get NBR value of pixel of interest
                itemImage1=band2Image1asArray[row][col]
                print("itemImage1: ",itemImage1)
                #if pixel has no value, don´t do anything
                if itemImage1== band2Image1.GetNoDataValue() or itemImage1==-32768:
                    print("row number: ", row)
                    print("col number: ", col)
                    print ("image 1 pixel with no data value; initiating with another image")

                #if pixel has a value, proceed
                else:
                    #reset switch to False (switch is used to skip images
                    switch1=False
                    #list of numbers for image 2: from index of image + 1 to index of image 1 + 8
                    listImg2=[indexImage1+1,indexImage1+2,indexImage1+3,indexImage1+4,indexImage1+5,indexImage1+6,indexImage1+7,indexImage1+8]
                    for indexImg2 in listImg2:
                        print("length list image: ", len(ListImages))
                        print ("Current indexImg2: ", indexImg2)
                        print("row number: ", row)
                        print("col number: ", col)
                        #if number of image 2 is above number of images in list, stop (all images have been processed)
                        if indexImg2>=len(ListImages):
                            break
                        #if not, proceed
                        else:
                            
                            #open next image in the list (next date)
                            image2=gdal.Open(ListImages[indexImg2])
                            img2Path=os.path.abspath(ListImages[indexImg2])
                            print ("path image 2: " + img2Path)
                            #get image 2 NDVI value for this pixel
                            band1Image2 = image2.GetRasterBand(1)
                            band1Image2AsArray = band1Image2.ReadAsArray()
                            itemNDVIimage2=band1Image2AsArray[row][col]
                            print("item image 2, Band 1 (NDVI): ", itemNDVIimage2)
                            #get image 2 NBR value for this pixel
                            band2Image2 = image2.GetRasterBand(2)
                            band2Image2AsArray = band2Image2.ReadAsArray()
                            #print ("Image 2, Band 2:",band2Image2AsArray)
                            itemImage2=band2Image2AsArray[row][col]
                            print("item image 2: ", itemImage2)
                            #if image 2 has no value for NBR band, stop and continue with next image 2 
                            if itemImage2== band2Image2.GetNoDataValue() or itemImage2==-32768:
                                print ("image 2 pixel with no data value; initiating with another image")
                            else:
                                #calculate dNBR, NBR and NDVI difference between the two images
                                dNBR=itemImage1-itemImage2
                                RdNBR=dNBR/(math.sqrt(abs(itemImage1)))
                                NDVIdiff=1-itemNDVIimage2/itemNDVIimage1
                                print ("dNBR: ",dNBR)
                                print ("RdNBR: ", RdNBR)
                                print ("NDVI difference: ", NDVIdiff)
                                #if dNBR equals exactly 0, it means that image 1 and image 2 were the same; stop and continue with next image
                                if dNBR==0:
                                    print("same image for image 1 and image2; initiating with another image for image 2")
                                #if dNBR, NBR or NDVI difference values are under thresholds, stop and continue with next image
                                elif dNBR<dNBRthreshold or RdNBR<RdNBRthreshold or NDVIdiff<NDVIdiffThreshold :
                                    print("dNBR or RdNBR or NDVIdiff under threshold; continue with next image for image 2")

                                else:  
                                    #open empty image and set new dNBR and RdNBR and date values in first, second and third band respectively. in ArrayStack, first number is number of band (first is zero) then row then column.
                                    #if dNBR  or RdNBR values is above value already saved in the array or if current value is empty (nan), overwrite it; else, don't overwrite it
                                    print ("current dNBR value for this cell in arrayStack: ",arrayStack[cntrForBand][row][col])
                                    if (dNBR>arrayStack[cntrForBand][row][col] and RdNBR>arrayStack[cntrForBand+1][row][col]) or (math.isnan(arrayStack[cntrForBand][row][col])):
                                        #keep dNBR, RdNBR and date value in first, second and third of the three bands (hence cntrForBand for dNBR, cntrForBand+1 for RdNBR and cntrForBand+2 for Date)
                                        arrayStack[cntrForBand][row][col]= dNBR
                                        arrayStack[cntrForBand+1][row][col]= RdNBR
                                        #arrayStack[0,0,0]=dNBR
                                            #date value put in second band
                                        date=int(img2Path[-15:-8])
                                        arrayStack[cntrForBand+2][row][col]= date
                                        print ("arrayStack updated: ",arrayStack)
                                        #turn switch on to skip 22 images (forest and therefore fire won't come back soon...)
                                        switch1= True
                                    else:
                                        #print(arrayStack)
                                        print ("dNBR value lower than value already in arrayStack; not changing value")
                    #if one value of dNBR and RdNBR is above threshold during loops with image 1 and 2, then skip 6 monts and continue with image 1 + 22
                    #else, continue with image 1 + 7
                    if switch1==True:
                        next(islice(iterListImages, 44, 44), None)  # consume 22
                        print("a value has been found for this set of 8 images; continuing with image 1 + 44")
                        #cntr for band increments with 3 so that next round three other bands of arrayStack get the dNBR, NBR and Date values
                        cntrForBand=cntrForBand+3
                        print ("cntrForBand=",cntrForBand)
                    else:
                        #if no high value found, go to image+7 in list
                        next(islice(iterListImages, 7, 7), None)
                        print("No value found for this set of 8 images; continuing with next image (+1)")
                        
    print ("done!!!!")
    print (arrayStack)
    np.save(path+"\\FINAL.csv", arrayStack)
    print("file FINAL.csv saved")
     
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        listFolders= [ f.path for f in os.scandir("C:\\incendios\\Temp3") if f.is_dir() ]
        print (listFolders, type(listFolders))
        cpuCount = os.cpu_count() 
        print ("number of core: ",cpuCount)
        p = Pool(10)
        print(p.map(proc,listFolders))
```

If a run a very simple code that uses NumPy, it works perfectly fine and uses 100% CPU and all 10 cores:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import numpy as np

start = time.time()
print("hello")

array=np.random.rand(3000,3000)

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    mult=np.dot(array, array)
    print (mult)
    return mult

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(50):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

I know that NumPy can cause some [issues with multiprocessing](https://shahhj.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/numpy-and-blas-no-problemo/), but this doesn't seem to be the issue I have here.
So I guess there is something wrong with my code that makes it difficult to process with multiple cores. Is there anything I can do to improve it?
PS: I'm using Windows 10 64 bits and python 3.5.0 and the script works fine without multiprocessing...

EDIT:
to answer Mark Stechell´s question: Actually I have 10 folders; each folder has around 900 rasters that cover one area per folder, with one raster every 8 days from 2000 to 2020. These rasters are satellite images that I have already processed; the first band is a Vegetation Index (called NDVI) and the second one is a Burn Area Index (NBR, a basic index used to identify forestry fires); in this script, I use those data to calculate other indexes (dNBR and RdNBR; the last one is a relative index, it means that I compare NBR indexes of two different dates to detect a significant change). If those indexes are high enough (threshold are defined at the beginning of the script) which means that a forestry fire was detected, I keep the NDVI and RdNBR values in a numpy array with the date. But I only do this comparison with 8 following dates; if no significant value has been found, the script goes on with another image in the list and its 7 following images (chronologically); If a significant value has been found, the script jumps 22 images in the list because another forestry fire won´t happen again in this area before a long time..

Following mkrieger1´s advice, I am trying to simplify this as much as a can to see where the problem is. I am also going to try to use Pool in the very simple code I mentioned to see if this works

Comment: Could you please reduce this to a [mre]?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, please? Do you have 8 images of the same location captured on different dates in each folder and you want the brightest value of each pixel across those dates, or something like that?

Comment: Aren't you doing different things in the two scripts? You spawn different processes in one and use `Pool` in another.

Answer (score 0):

Following mkrieger1's advice, I've tried to run my script line by line to see where the problem was. It is clearly related to the GDAL library.

The `getNoDataValue()`, `getMinimum()` and `getMaximum()` functions are the problem here for multiprocessing. I have change the code with functions related to other library (`if itemImage1==getNoDataValue ()` has been changed with `if math.isnan(x)` for instance).

Now it is working perfectly.